# Create Tablespace is not working on Postgres - Ubuntu - NTFS

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, tablespaces

I cant create a new tablespace in mounted directory

```
psql -U sysuser -d postgres -c "CREATE TABLESPACE dadospostgres LOCATION '/media/tiago/Dados/Postgres/Bancos';"
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/media/tiago/Dados/Postgres/Bancos": Permission denied

psql -U sysuser -d postgres -c "CREATE TABLESPACE dadospostgres LOCATION '/media/tiago/Dados/Postgres';"
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/media/tiago/Dados/Postgres": Permission denied
```

Folders permissions:

```
root@tiago:/media/tiago/Dados# ls -l /media/
total 4
drwxr-x---+ 4 root root 4096 out 14 11:29 tiago

root@tiago:/media/tiago/Dados# ls -l /media/tiago/ | grep Dados
drwxrwxrwx 1 tiago tiago 8192 out 14 10:52 Dados

root@tiago:/media/tiago/Dados# ls -l /media/tiago/Dados/ | grep Postgres
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres         144 out 14 11:33 Postgres

root@tiago:/media/tiago/Dados# ls -l /media/tiago/Dados/Postgres/
total 0
drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 0 out 14 11:33 Bancos
```

Mounted disk

```
root@tiago:/media/tiago/Dados# lsblk -O
└─nvme1n1p2
     nvme1n1p2
           /dev/nvme1n1p2
                259:9    188,9G 953,9G ntfs     765G    80% /media/tia Dados 56836A8F5F3C7018                     3af9eb40-7c61-4a6f-a748-180335979b27 dos    ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7           01418683-fa44-448e-92c1-234d67229098           128  0  0       0              953,9G       root  disk  brw-rw----         0    512      0     512     512    0 none      255 part        0      512B       2T         0    0B uuid.df8e86d6-8a47-9916-2e43-8e8b6efdb7cd    0 nvme1n1

root@tiago:/media/tiago/Dados# cat /etc/fstab
UUID=56836A8F5F3C7018  /media/tiago/Dados       ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0
```

I need the free space in this mounted disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `postgres` has no "execute" permissions on the `/media` directory. Hence the error.

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /media` and `sudo chmod +x /media/tiago` fixed the problem, tankyou